# DataTables FixedColumn "Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedColumns is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to use datatables' FixedColumns plugin. Nothing is working. I have dropped down to the example code straight off of the website, here:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
    } );

    new FixedColumns( oTable );
} );
```

Script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://address/testbed/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://address/testbed/js/datatables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://address/testbed/js/fixedcolumns.js"></script>
```

All scripts are loading fine according to chrome. The error I am getting is "Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedColumns is not defined."

jQuery 1.11.0

datatables 1.9.4

FixedColumns 3.0.1-dev (I've tried various versions, this is the latest releast off github)

What's up?

Comment: What does your script tags look like? Are the files loaded? My guess is you are missing the FixedColumns.js

Comment: Added the script tags. That's definitely not the issue though. Chrome reports they're all successfully loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( oTable );
```

which is what the [documentation](http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/) actually says for me too.

The "constructor" FixedColumns is only defined in the IIFE which wraps the plugin and exports as `$.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns`

Comment: But it says it like the OPs here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/index.html

Comment: You're correct, it does say that there. But looking at the current master on github (3.0.1-dev at the time of this writing) and at least from 3.0.0 onward, it won't work the way it's described there.

Comment: Well, that works... While Datatables is pretty awesome, I find their documentation way too fragmented to be useful... Oh well.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you there. It seems if you navigate from Examples on their homepage and pick any for FixedColumns, you land at the url epascarello linked. However if you happen to go to Extras, and navigate to examples for FixedColumns from there, you land at the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
    } );


new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( oTable , {
            leftColumns: 3 //specifies how many left columns should be fixed.
        });
```